How to find out why node-tap does not exit
I was running tests with node-tap today, and I ran into the issue that my test was running forever and then timing out.
I stumbled upon a few SO threads (like this one), and it pointed me into the right direction: I had forgotten to close the DB connection. (I'm using fastify too)
The issue is now fixed but I wonder: how could I have debugged that? Does TAP show in logs somewhere why a given test is not considered as over? I tried running with --debug but it didn't help a lot. I might have missed the important line though
